# Azure profile instant build/publish

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

So I have an WebAppService which contains virtual directories. Whenever I create a new profile to deploy the current project to a new virtual directory, when I press "create", Visual Studio automatically run the build and publish the project on the root directory ("/").
Since I want to publish on a specific route (let's say "/foo"), I first need to wait for the build/deploy process to finish (I can't find a way to abort the process) which will override whatever I have on my root folder ("/"). Isn't there any way to avoid this automatic build/publish process?

Answer (score 0):

> I first need to wait for the build/deploy process to finish (I can't find a way to abort the process) which will override whatever I have on my root folder ("/"). Isn't there any way to avoid this automatic build/publish process?

If you want to publish the part of your project, there is no need to create the new profile. We could directly publish the file or folder with files to the Azure portal from Visual Studio.

[image]

**Updated:**

We could update the publish profile to do that, more details please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

**Update 2:**

> Whenever I create a new profile to deploy the current project to a new virtual directory, when I press "create", Visual Studio automatically run the build and publish the project on the root directory ("/")`

As you mentioned that if we create a new profile, it will publish it directly. If we want to edit the profile during creating new profile, we could give our [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps) to Azure team.

Except creating a new profile, we could publish the WebApp from the existing profile. Or we could use Azure WebApp Kudu [Zip API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) to do that.

```
PUT https://{user}:{password}@{FunctionAppname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/{path}  # example path:site/wwwroot/foo
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tom. However, I don't want to publish only one folder, i want to publish a whole project (which is contained in the solution). A "visual map" relation would be:
https://imgur.com/GHFq2WQ

Comment: If we want to publish the website to the virtual directory, we could update the publish profile to do that, I have updated the answer, please refer to it.

Comment: Tom, the key point here is the "update the publish profile". Before the update, it *always* runs a publish process  (the settings and so on even appear grayed out), meaning it will override what's on the "/" folder (the root folder) on a first time

Comment: As you mentioned that if create a new profile, it will publish the WebApp to Azure root directory. we could give our idea to Azure. My work around is that we could use Kudu Zip API to publish our project. More details please refer to my update2.

Comment: Tom, thank your very much for your persistence. I will write a feedback to azure team